# How do I dismiss the TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to dismiss an existing TabView in my SwiftUI application.  Basically, it works like this:

The SceneDelegate launches a view called MainScreenView()

```
struct MainScreenView: View {
    
    @State var isLoadingViewEnabled = false
    @State var isSuccessViewEnabled = false
    @State var showLoopingBlobs = false
    @State var showTabView = false
    
    @ObservedObject var user = UsrAccount()
    @ObservedObject var authManager = FirebaseAuthManager()
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !showTabView {
                ZStack {
                    Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1647058824, green: 0.6862745098, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            LogoView()
                            LoginView(user: user)
                                .padding(.bottom, 100)
                            LoginButton(
                                isLoadingViewEnabled: $isLoadingViewEnabled,
                                isSuccessViewEnabled: $isSuccessViewEnabled,
                                showTabView: $showTabView,
                                user: user,
                                authManager: authManager
                            )
                            ForgotPassword(user: user, authManager: authManager)
                                .padding(.top, 20)
                            RegisterNewUserView(authManager: authManager, user: user)
                                .padding(.top, 20)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        .background(
                            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1647058824, green: 0.6862745098, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1))
                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
//                            BlobRotationView(showLoopingBlobs: $showLoopingBlobs)
                        )
                        
                        if isLoadingViewEnabled {
                            LoadingView()
                        }
                        if isSuccessViewEnabled {
                            LoginSuccessView()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight*0.20)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.85))
                .onTapGesture { KeyboardInteraction.hideKeyboard() }
            } else {
                TabBar(user: user, authManager: authManager, keyboardResponder: keyboardResponder)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once there is a successful login to Firebase (code not shown), a tab view will get shown:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBar: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @ObservedObject var user: UsrAccount
    @ObservedObject var authManager: FirebaseAuthManager
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder: KeyboardResponder
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            HomeView(user: user, authManager: authManager, keyboardResponder: keyboardResponder)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedTab = 0
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Home")
            }
            .tag(0)
            
            ScheduleLessonsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedTab = 1
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Schedule")
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            PurchaseLessonsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedTab = 2
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cart.fill.badge.plus")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Purchase")
            }
            .tag(2)
            
            UpdateProfileView(authManager: authManager, user: user)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedTab = 3
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Profile")
            }
            .tag(3)
            
            AboutUsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedTab = 4
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("About Us")
            }
            .tag(4)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}

struct TabBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBar(user: UsrAccount(), authManager: FirebaseAuthManager(), keyboardResponder: KeyboardResponder())
    }
}
```

As you can see from the TabView, the HomeView is the initial tab that is shown.  I have setup an exit button in that view to log the user out of Firebase and send the user back to the login screen (MainScreenView).

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var user: UsrAccount
    @ObservedObject var authManager: FirebaseAuthManager
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder: KeyboardResponder
    @State var isCardSelected = false
    @State var didSignOutUser = false

    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            if didSignOutUser {
                MainScreenView()
            } else {
                ZStack {
                    Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                didSignOutUser = authManager.signOut()
                                print("**** Sign Out status: \(didSignOutUser)")
                            }) {
                                Text("X")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.08235294118, green: 0.2274509804, blue: 0.4078431373, alpha: 1)))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
                                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                                    .padding(.leading)
                            }
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Welcome!")
                                    .font(.system(.title))
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.07843137255, green: 0.3294117647, blue: 0.4078431373, alpha: 1)))
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                ForEach(homeCardData) { item in
                                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                                        HomeCardView(homeCard: item, isCardSelected: self.$isCardSelected)
                                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:
                                                Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX - 30) / -30
                                            ), axis: (x: 0, y: 10, z: 0))
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(30)
                            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Here are your upcoming classes:")
                                    .font(.system(.body))
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.07843137255, green: 0.3294117647, blue: 0.4078431373, alpha: 1)))
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        
                        NoClassView()
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the TabView still shows up at the bottom of the MainScreenView, which is wrong.  It also seems that the user isn't even logged out.

The SignOut method is called on my FirebaseAuthManager class:

```
    func signOut() -> Bool {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.user = nil
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
```

The above method is returning "true", so it seems that it is signing the user out.

So.. 2 questions:

1. How can I confirm the user is signed out when the user is sent back to MainScreenView?
2. How can I make sure the TabView gets destroyed when the user chooses to exit from one of the screens in the TabView?